# Changing name while assigning and getting value from and to json - Objectmapper java

Tags: java, json, mapping

While assigning values from DTO to different entity names, I assigned correctly with the help of JsonProperty. FrontEnd expecting in a different name. Values for DTO object will get from different object. That I have to assign to entity. Instead of using plain java and copying, am using objectmapper. Here then entity values will be used by frontend. How to print the entity values in different name? Please check below code.

//DTO Class
    import java.util.List;

```
public class StaffDTO {
    private String nameDT;
    private List<String> skillDT;

    //Getter and Setters
}
```

//Entity Class

```
import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "nameDT",
    "skillDT"
})
public class Staff {

    @JsonProperty("nameDT")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("skillDT")
    private List<String> skills;    

    //Getter and Setters    
}
```

//Call Method

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


public class SeatMapCall1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            StaffDTO staffDTO = createDummyObject();

            System.out.println(convertObjectToJson(staffDTO));

            Staff staff= convertJsonToObject(convertObjectToJson(staffDTO),Staff.class);

            System.out.println(convertObjectToJson(staff));


        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static <T> T convertJsonToObject(String jsonStrRes,
            Class<T> classArg) {
        T resObj = null;
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            resObj = mapper.readValue(jsonStrRes, classArg);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resObj;
    }

    public static <T> String convertObjectToJson(T obj) {
        String jsonStringReq = null;
        ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            jsonStringReq = objMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return jsonStringReq;
    }

    private static StaffDTO createDummyObject() {

        StaffDTO staffDTO = new StaffDTO();

        staffDTO.setNameDT("mkyong");

        List<String> skills = new ArrayList<>();
        skills.add("java");
        skills.add("python");

        staffDTO.setSkillDT(skills);

        return staffDTO;

    }

}
```

//Displays output as

```
{"nameDT":"mkyong","skillDT":["java","python"]}
{"nameDT":"mkyong","skillDT":["java","python"]}
```

But I want

```
{"nameDT":"mkyong","skillDT":["java","python"]}
{"name":"mkyong","skills":["java","python"]}
```

If I use the below getter and setters in Staff class, I am getting expected as below

```
{"nameDT":"mkyong","skillDT":["java","python"]}
{"nameDT":"mkyong","skillDT":["java","python"],"name":"mkyong","skills":["java","python"]}
```

Here it includes both nameDT, skillDT and name, skills. I don't need nameDT, skillDT.

```
@JsonProperty("nameDT") 
private String nameDT; 
@JsonProperty("skillDT") 
private List<String> skillDT; 
public String getName() 
{ return nameDT; } 
public void setName(String nameDT) 
{ this.nameDT = nameDT; } 
public List<String> getSkill() 
{ return skillDT; } 
public void setSkill(List<String> skillDT) 
{ this.skillDT = skillDT; }
```

Comment: A)  dont go with empty catch blocks, there is no point in ignoring errors B) sorry, I don't get it, you want instances of the **same** DTO class to be formatted differently. Maybe missed that, but why?

Comment: Well, you said that the name property must be serialized ot/parsed from a nameDT property in JSON. So the output you get is quite expected. If the JSON contains a serialized DTO, then read the JSON as a DTO, and then use plain Java to transform that DTO object into a Staff instance. Why would you serialize and parse a Staff in the first place? It's precisely the role of a DTO (Data Transfer Object) to be serialized to JSON to be transferred.

Comment: @GhostCat - B) FrontEnd expecting in a different name. Values for DTO object will get from different object. That I have to assign to entity. Instead of using plain java and copying, am using objectmapper. Here then entity values will be used by frontend.

Comment: @GhostCat - Appologies, I edited now. Did you get my requirement now? There should be some way to do this. Otherwise I have to go for plain java code mapping. When the class is big, we need such way rather doing manual mapping.

Comment: More readable, yes. But I am still not getting to the core of your requirement. But at least your question should be in a state now where others figure an answer ...